# Notifications won't appear

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I launch my app, I set the time in my activity and I wait for the notification, it doesn't appear, it doesn't work.

Here's my activity, if you find the error tell me please.. Thanks for your help :)

```
package app.alexdickson.com.workout1;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageButton botoFlexio;
ImageButton botoAbdominals;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
int hour_x;
int minute_x;
int hourDefinitivaFlexio;
int minuteDefinitvaFlexio;
int hourDefinitivaAbs;
int minuteDefinitivaAbs;
PendingIntent pendingIntent1;
PendingIntent pendingIntent2;
Context context;
AlarmManager alarmManager1;
AlarmManager alarmManager2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    this.context = this;
    botoFlexio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.botoFlexio);
    botoAbdominals = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.botoAbdominals);
    botoFlexio.setOnClickListener(this);
    botoAbdominals.setOnClickListener(this);
    alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


}
 private void alarmMethod1(){
    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, NotifyService1.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent1 =PendingIntent.getService(this,0,myIntent1,0);

    Calendar calendari1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendari1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute_x);
    calendari1.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour_x);

    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendari1.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent1);


}


private void alarmMethod2(){
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, NotifyService2.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent2 =PendingIntent.getService(this,0,myIntent2,0);

    Calendar calendari2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendari2.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute_x);
    calendari2.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour_x);

    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendari2.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent2);


}










@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.botoFlexio:
            botoFlexio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flexioclicat);
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            hourDefinitivaFlexio = hour_x;
            minuteDefinitvaFlexio = minute_x;

            alarmMethod1();

            break;

        case R.id.botoAbdominals:
            botoAbdominals.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abdominalsclicat);
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            hourDefinitivaAbs = hour_x;
            minuteDefinitivaAbs = minute_x;

            alarmMethod2();

            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == DIALOG_ID)

        return new TimePickerDialog(Main2Activity.this, kTimePickerListener, hour_x, minute_x, true);
    return null;
}

protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hour_x = hourOfDay;
                minute_x = minute;
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, hour_x + ": " + minute_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

}

Here's where the intent goes: (There are two of them but they are the same, it only changes the numbers)

```
package app.alexdickson.com.workout1;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;



public class NotifyService1 extends Service {

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationManager nNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Main3Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Hora d'entrenar!")
            .setContentText("Clica per començar entrenament de pit i braços")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(sound)
            .build();

    nNM.notify(1,mNotify);

}
```

}

And here's my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main4Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register `NotifyService1` and `NotifyService2` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.